# LDAP vs MYSQL.. JA-SIG CAS with LDAP vs CAS with MySQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap, cas

LDAP vs MYSQL.. JA-SIG CAS with LDAP vs CAS with MySQL.

Right now we have user id, password and roles in LDAP and is working with CAS and Spring Secuirty. My firm is looking to remove the data from LDAP and to put it into MySQL.  I would love to hear comments on why we should stay with LDAP.

Comment: Ldap is a protocol, not a storage system.

Comment: @RobUa - I think the OP means an LDAP *service* ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP is a directory service. It's primary purpose for existence is as a repository of security information. Trying to store this same kind of information in MySQL would basically mean replicating alot of the functionality that LDAP already provides. Typically you see corporations migrating from custom database solutions *to* directory services - not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

More systems, particularly legacy systems, especially on Unix, can easily use LDAP as their credential store. If you use or plan to use any of those systems, you can gain the benefit of a single source of truth and offer your users a shared credential (i.e. same username/password) across these systems.

Interfacing with SQL systems in this regard is not as prevalent.